# How to set up Win+Space for rotating or toggling keyboard layouts both in tty and Gnome with X.Org?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, input-languages, tty, debian-bookworm

Let's say we wish to have keyboard layouts `de`, `ru`, `fr`, and `es` in Gnome with X.Org and at least `de` and `ru` (and optionally but not necessarily `fr` and `es`) in plain old text-mode consoles. The layout-rotation key combination should be ⊞+␣ (i.e., [Win]+[Space]) in any case.

As for X.Org & Gnome, this is easy:

Opening *Einstellungen* (German for *Settings*) > *Tastatur* (German for *Keyboard*) yields

[image: input settings in Gnome]

A click on *Tastenkombinationen anzeigen und anpassen* (German for *View and customize keyboard shortcuts*) leads us to

[image: keyboard keys]

which is what we want: *Super+Leertaste* is German for *super+spacebar*.

What to do for the text consoles, which are reachable via Ctrl+Alt+F2 through Ctrl+Alt+F6 (except the consoles open for a user's Gnome sessions)?  As of now, I found

```bash
$ sudo cat /etc/default/keyboard 
XKBLAYOUT="de,ru"
XKBVARIANT=","
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
```

The Alt+Shift key combination is unwished, and a Scroll LED is not so useful for more than two layouts. The Alt+Shift key combination also shadows the standard Ctrl+Alt+Shift+↑ and Ctrl+Alt+Shift+↓ for moving the current Window a workspace up and down (for vertical workplaces); we have to issue

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options []
```

to remove this shadowing.  What to do instead of this contents of /etc/default/keyboard for the white-on-black plaintext teletype consoles tty1…tty6?  Who created /etc/default/keyboard anyway? On my machine,

```bash
$ LANG=en_US sudo dpkg -S /etc/default/keyboard 
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/default/keyboard
```

:-(